# Android SDK Missing

Tags: android

Below is my current setup in my PC.

Eclise Indigo
Android SDK Platform - API 15
ADT version 18

I developed a simple android application, and was able to succesffully launch it in emulator and android phone. I need to test with galaxy tablet emulator. I found GALAXY Tab Android API 8 in Android SKD Manager. When I choose to install I'm prompted with a message "Missing SDK Platform Android, API 8". My questions are:

Where can I download Android sdk api 8?
Can api versions 15 and 8 coexist?
Can I get api 8 version etup within eclipse?
How do make this version as one of the target in the AVD Manager?

Please advise.

Comment: Did you install all packages from the Android version 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your "SDK Manager" through your start menu, and once the SDK Manager has loaded select the Package "Android 2.2 (API 8)" and click the button in the lower right "Install Packages."

If you want to access the SDK Manager through Eclipse go to the "Window" tab at the top and then you should see the option "Android SDK Manager," click on that and follow the same steps as outlined above.

As far as your question "Can api versions 15 and 8 coexist," the answer is yes.